# Impossible to get the value of a form's id in certains conditions

Tags: javascript, html, dom

It seems that it is impossible to get the *expected* value of a `<form>`'s id when an `<input>` or an `<img>` within the `<form>` has an id or a name with "id" as value.

Example:

```
<form id="test">
    <input id="id" />
</form>
```

Calling `document.querySelector('form').id` returns `HTMLInputElement` instead of `"test"`.

Here is a JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/zyy54jmj/6/

Do you know why this is the case ? And is there a way to fix this ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well you can get any attribute value of an element like this:

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll('element')[0].getAttribute("attribute")
```

in this case it's the id of a form so

```
var formId = document.querySelectorAll('form')[0].getAttribute("id")
```

It would help to know what you are trying to achieve though because this isn't good practice. You are basically traversing the whole DOM to find the id of a form and use it how?

Comment: Actually, I'm writing an extension I ran into this while testing it on a random website. I was using the jQuery method $.prop to get the id value, then as I saw it was not returning the expected value I wanted to use plain Javascript by using the Element.id property, but it still did not return the expected value. Now with your answer, I understand the difference between properties and attributes. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

There's a difference here between "invalid" names and "taken" names, in regards to DOM properties.

All of these a valid methods/properties that can be found on FORM elements (due to interface inheritance), and all of them can be overwritten by same-named fields. Therefore, I would suggest to avoid these names, not to run into accidental conflicts:

```
ELEMENT_NODE
ATTRIBUTE_NODE
TEXT_NODE
CDATA_SECTION_NODE
ENTITY_REFERENCE_NODE
ENTITY_NODE
PROCESSING_INSTRUCTION_NODE
COMMENT_NODE
DOCUMENT_NODE
DOCUMENT_TYPE_NODE
DOCUMENT_FRAGMENT_NODE
NOTATION_NODE
nodeName
nodeValue
nodeType
parentNode
childNodes
firstChild
lastChild
previousSibling
nextSibling
attributes
ownerDocument
insertBefore
replaceChild
removeChild
appendChild
hasChildNodes
cloneNode
normalize
isSupported
namespaceURI
prefix
localName
hasAttributes

id
title
lang
dir
className

elements
length
name
acceptCharset
action
enctype
method
target
submit
reset
item
namedItem
```

Comment: Actually I'm writing an extension and I ran into this while testing it on a random website. I would never have done such a thing :)